# How to fix a problem on Controller configuration?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a problem with the anotations in the class controller in my spring boot project. What methods should i use?

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/products")
 public class ProductController {

 /**
     * Only a Test
 */
 @Autowired
 private ProductService productService;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have at least the CRUD methods, something like that:

```
@GetMapping
public String index(Model model) {

    List<Product> products = productService.searchAll();

    model.addAttribute("products", products);

    return "product/index"; 
}

@GetMapping("/addProduct")
public String add(Product product, Model model) {

    logger.info("Creating new 'Product' on data source");
    this.productService.inserir(product);

    return "product/addProduct";
}

@GetMapping("/editProduct/{id}")
public String edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

    logger.info("Find 'Product' Id: {} on data source", id);
    Product product = this.productService.searchById(id);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    return "product/editProduct";
}

@GetMapping("/deleteProduct/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

    logger.info("Deleting 'Product' Id:{} from data source", id);
    this.productService.deletar(id);

    return index(model);
}

@PostMapping("/saveProduct")
public String save(@Valid Product product, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return add(product, model);
    }

    if (product.getId() != 0) {
        logger.info("Updating 'Product' Id: {} on data source", product.getId());
        this.productService.atualizar(product);
    } else {
        logger.info("Creating new 'Product' on data source");
        this.productService.inserir(product);
    }

    return index(model);
}
```